# onclick fires with no issues but addEventListener requires multiple clicks to work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, addeventlistener

I've tried this a few different ways.  I'm attempting to create an event for a button that toggles an elements visibility on and off.  for some reason when I use .onclick it works fine.  Each time I click the button it toggles the element visibility as expected.  However when I attempt to swap  .onClick for addEventListener the button has to be clicked multiple times for it to work.  It seems intermittent.  It may work on the 1st click one time and then the next time it may require 2 or 3.

```js
function showTime() {
    options = {weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit'}
    var date = new Date();
    var hr = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var sec = date.getSeconds();
    var period = "am";

    if(hr == 0){
        hr = 12;
    }

    if(hr > 12){
        hr = hr - 12;
        period = "pm";
    }

    min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
    sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

    var time = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + period; 
    document.getElementById("displayTime").innerHTML = time;
    document.getElementById("displayDate").innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

    
    var startTime = setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

    //Set Alarm
    var set = document.getElementById("setButton");

    set.onclick = function(){
        var timeVis = document.getElementById("displayTime");
        if (timeVis.style.display !== 'none') {
            timeVis.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            timeVis.style.display = 'block';
        }        
    }

}

showTime();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Clock </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="displayTime" onLoad="showTime()" ></div>
        <input type="text" id="setInput">
        <button id="setButton">set</button>
        <div id="displayDate"></div>
        <script src="DigitalClock.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below are the two alternate ways I attempted to use add an event listener

```
var set = document.getElementById("setButton");

set.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var timeVis = document.getElementById("displayTime");
    if (timeVis.style.display !== 'none') {
        timeVis.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        timeVis.style.display = 'block';
    }        
});
```

---

```
var set = document.getElementById("setButton");
var timeVis = document.getElementById("displayTime");

function vis(){
    if (timeVis.style.display !== 'none') {
        timeVis.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        timeVis.style.display = 'block';
    }        
};

timeVis.addEventListener('click', vis);
```

Comment: Remove the `onLoad="showTime()"` and add another listener for that instead.  Also you might review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Memory_issues

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `addEventListener` inside the `showTime()` function, so each time showTime() is executed, you bind a new listener.

Now because of this:

```
var startTime = setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
```

The function is executed each second. As a result, after a couple of seconds, when you click one time on the button, the toggle part is executed multiple times.

On the other hand, with `set.onclick`, you only redefine the onclick property of the element, this is why it's working as expected.